# How a thread can commit suicide with syscall only in C Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, system-calls, kill

I wrote the following code, the goal is to make thread to suicide **with syscall** (without calling `pthread_exit()`).

So I create two threads and select one that get its thread id, and send SIGKILL to itself with `tkill()`

The problem is that all the process terminates, not only the selected thread.

Why is that? How can I makes thread to suicide with syscall only?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <sys/syscall.h>


void *myThreadFun(void *vargp) 
{ 

    int tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    if(tid %2 ==0)
    {
        printf("kill thread id ! = %ld \n",tid);
        syscall(SYS_tkill,tid,9); 
    }
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Thread ID: %d\n", tid);
        sleep(2); 
    }
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int i; 
    pthread_t tid; 

    printf("main thread id = %ld \n",syscall(SYS_gettid)); 
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThreadFun,  NULL); 

    char tmp;
    scanf("%c",&tmp); 
    return 0; 
}
```

output:

```
main thread id = 11911 
kill thread id ! = 11912 
Killed
```

Comment: `sys_tkill` kills a process. You need to use [`pthread_kill`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html)

Comment: @fredrik but I want to implement that only with syscall without call to another function, can I implement that with syscall?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain **why** you want to implement this without using `pthread_exit` or other `pthread_...` functions? If you implement this with `pthread_exit` or `pthread_kill` first and run your program with `strace` you might be able to shee how the `pthread_...` functions are implemented. Or look at the source code of the pthread library

Comment: @Bodo I have tried to look at https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/nptl/pthread_exit.c.html but couldn't find the implementation for that

Comment: Please add all information to the question instead of answering in comments. The source code calls `__do_cancel ();`, so the next step would be to search for the source code of this function. If you download the whole sourcecode it might be easier to search in all files. If you use an IDE you might even be able to jump directly to the definition of an identifier at the cursor/mouse pointer position.

Comment: I just noticed that the referenced sourcecode is hyperlinked, so you don't necessarily nead an IDE, but the code is nor easy to understand. Try using a system call trace.

Comment: It looks to me like the `_exit` syscall actually causes only the calling thread to terminate, so you could do that.  Calling `_exit()` from C actually invokes the system call `exit_group` which kills all threads.

Comment: @fredrik No, `tkill` kills a _thread_ and _not_ a process. `tkill` is the deprecated version of `tgkill`. And, `pthread_kill` is passed a `pthread_t`. It gets the `tid` from that and then calls `tgkill`. So, while `tkill` is less safe than `tgkill` [if a thread terminates and the tid is reused by an unrelated process], it still just kills the thread.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "kill this thread only" [signal disposition](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html); there are only "ignore", "terminate the entire process", "terminate the entire process and dump a core file", "stop (pause) the entire process", and "continue the entire process if it is stopped (paused)".  You cannot even choose the disposition per se; only between the default disposition for that particular signal, "ignore", or an userspace signal handler function.

There is really only one option: the [SYS_exit syscall](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html).

In C, you can do this via

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

static inline void exit_thread(void) __attribute__((noreturn));
static inline void exit_thread(void)
{
    syscall(SYS_exit, 0);
}
```

A real-world example always beats a snippet, I think.  Consider the following program:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

void *thread_function(void *payload)
{
#ifdef DO_EXIT
    const int exit_code = (int)(intptr_t)payload;
    fprintf(stderr, "Running thread_function(%p); calling syscall(SYS_exit, %d).\n", payload, exit_code);
    fflush(stderr);
    syscall(SYS_exit, exit_code);
#else
    fprintf(stderr, "Running thread_function(%p); calling pthread_exit(%p).\n", payload, payload);
    fflush(stderr);
    pthread_exit(payload);
#endif

    return NULL;    /* Never reached */
}

int main(void)
{
    void *const payload = thread_function;  /* Just some random pointer value */
    pthread_t   thread_id;
    void       *thread_status;
    int         err;

    printf("Calling pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_function, %p): ", payload);
    fflush(stdout);

    err = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_function, payload);
    if (err) {
        printf("Failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Success.\n");
    printf("Calling pthread_join(thread_id, &thread_status): ");
    fflush(stdout);

    err = pthread_join(thread_id, &thread_status);
    if (err) {
        printf("Failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Success; thread_status == %p.\n", thread_status);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Save it as `example.c`, then compile one version, `ex1`, that uses pthread_exit():

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 example.c -pthread -o ex1
```

and another, `ex2`, that uses syscall(SYS_exit,):

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -DDO_EXIT -O2 example.c -pthread -o ex2
```

To see exactly what is happening, run each example under strace, logging each clone, write, futex, exit, and exit_group syscalls the program makes:

```
strace -f -e clone,write,futex,exit,exit_group -o ex1.log ./ex1
strace -f -e clone,write,futex,exit,exit_group -o ex2.log ./ex2
```

On my machine, `ex1.log` looks like

```
28703 write(1, "Calling pthread_create(&thread_i"..., 75) = 75
28703 clone(child_stack=0x7f11f9c14fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f11f9c159d0, tls=0x7f11f9c15700, child_tidptr=0x7f11f9c159d0) = 28704
28703 write(1, "Success.\n", 9)         = 9
28703 write(1, "Calling pthread_join(thread_id, "..., 49) = 49
28703 futex(0x7f11f9c159d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 28704, NULL <unfinished ...>
28704 write(2, "Running thread_function(0x563f0c"..., 79) = 79
28704 futex(0x7f11f94141a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
28704 exit(0)                           = ?
28703 <... futex resumed> )             = 0
28704 +++ exited with 0 +++
28703 write(1, "Success; thread_status == 0x563f"..., 42) = 42
28703 exit_group(0)                     = ?
28703 +++ exited with 0 +++
```

and `ex2.log` looks like

```
28707 write(1, "Calling pthread_create(&thread_i"..., 75) = 75
28707 clone(child_stack=0x7f42c7db8fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f42c7db99d0, tls=0x7f42c7db9700, child_tidptr=0x7f42c7db99d0) = 28708
28707 write(1, "Success.\n", 9)         = 9
28708 write(2, "Running thread_function(0x556b57"..., 80 <unfinished ...>
28707 write(1, "Calling pthread_join(thread_id, "..., 49 <unfinished ...>
28708 <... write resumed> )             = 80
28707 <... write resumed> )             = 49
28708 exit(1472596720 <unfinished ...>
28707 futex(0x7f42c7db99d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 28708, NULL <unfinished ...>
28708 <... exit resumed>)               = ?
28707 <... futex resumed> )             = 0
28708 +++ exited with 240 +++
28707 write(1, "Success; thread_status == (nil)."..., 33) = 33
28707 exit_group(0)                     = ?
28707 +++ exited with 0 +++
```

From their differences, and the fact that this is GNU C library version 2.27 running on x86-64 architecture, we can make a couple of important observations:

1. The GNU pthreads implementation uses a futex to pass the thread function return value, when the thread exits and is reaped (using `pthread_join()`) by another thread.
2. Aside from the futex used to pass the return value, `pthread_exit()` calls the `exit` syscall with exit status 0.

   (In fact, the [man 3 pthread_exit](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html) man page says so explicitly.)
3. When the thread exits (using the exit syscall), the exit status code is irrelevant.

If our thread function uses the syscall directly, cleanup functions registered by `atexit()` and `pthread_push()` will not be called, and if `pthread_join()` is called on this thread, the return value will essentially be `(void *)0` (`== NULL` in Linux, printed as `(nil)` by printf()/fprintf() `%p` format specifier).

Comment: Indeed, even `pthread_cancel()` doesn't operate by sending the thread a lethal signal, but by sending it a non-lethal signal (`SIGRTMIN`) whose handler causes it to  `SYS_exit` of its own accord.  I guess it makes sense: if you were able to kill a thread in a manner like `kill(2)`, there's no reason to think the rest of the process would be able to continue executing safely, and it could misbehave in all sorts of awful ways.  So if you want it dead and can't convince it to die voluntarily, you have to kill the whole process to be safe.

Comment: By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow!  With a great answer to start things off.